# Sed print between patterns the first match result

Tags: sed

the file like:

> File /home/user/
>
> int yl_init(void);
>
> File /home/user/
>
> int yl2_init(void);

I want use `sed -n '/File/,/;/p'` file
but it shows that

> File /home/user/
>
> int yl_init(void);
>
> File /home/user/
>
> int yl2_init(void);

I only want to get the first match result like:

> File /home/user/
>
> int yl_init(void);

I only want sed .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed);

```
sed '/File/,/;/!d;/;/q' file
```

- `/File/,/;/!d` delete all lines not between `File` and `;`
- `/;/q` quit on encountering a line containing `;`

Comment: why delete all lines not between File and ';',can i sed the strings and then quit on encountering a line containing ; directly?

Comment: @choujayyl sed normally prints all lines that are passed though it, unless the `-n` switch is activated. The `-n` is grep-like in nature, suppressing the output of lines unless explicitly printed by a `p` or `P` command. So `sed -n '/File/,/;/p' file` and `sed '/File/,/;/!d' file` have the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a the `q` command to cause sed to exit when the second pattern is matched:

```
sed -n '/File/,$p;/;/q'
```

Comment: Print every line between `/File/` and the end of the file, but quit after it prints a line with a semicolon.