# Recursive text search whithin lines before the grep match in shell

Tags: shell, recursion, awk, grep

I need help working with router config backup database. I need to get a list of interfaces that don't have `vrf` or `shutdown` in their configuration.
I get the list of all interfaces config passing the config file through `awk '/^interface/,/!/'`. This gives me the output below:

```
interface TenGigE0/3/0/0
 description 
 service-policy output QOS
 ipv4 mtu 1500
 ipv4 address 13.24.15.3 255.255.255.252
 carrier-delay up 3000 down 0
 load-interval 30
 dampening
!
interface TenGigE0/3/0/1
 description Link To 
!
interface TenGigE0/3/0/1.302
 description 
 vrf 1671
 ipv4 address 13.24.14.11 255.255.255.254
 encapsulation dot1q 302
```

Now, i am stuck trying to exclude the interfaces that contain `vrf` line. What i was trying to do is to grep for vrf, and when there is a match, remove the line that contains the word "interface" above. Unfortunately with no luck. Maybe someone has a more sophisticated solution.

Comment: See [this SO question/discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23934486/258523) for why the awk range expression isn't very useful in general and how rewriting to avoid it can let you do many more useful things (like dropping a section if it matches some other criteria as you want to do here).

Comment: @EtanReisner thank you. Will take a look. In general i am not bound to using awk, any shell tools can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the structured records awk can solve this problem.  Given your intermediate file

```
2$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="!\n"} !/vrf/' interface
```

will print the records without "vrf"

```
interface TenGigE0/3/0/0
 description
 service-policy output QOS
 ipv4 mtu 1500
 ipv4 address 13.24.15.3 255.255.255.252
 carrier-delay up 3000 down 0
 load-interval 30
 dampening
!
interface TenGigE0/3/0/1
 description Link To
!
```

Comment: This is magic:)) Thank you. I have spent a lot of time trying to find a solution, and it turned out to be so short:)))